# Best Practices to call on-premise webservice from Salesforce

Tags: apex, webservices, bestpractice

what is the best way to call the on-premise ws from salesforce? How can we make the connection and do the handshaking?

Comment: Is there a particular place in your code where you're stuck trying to implement a callout from Salesforce to an on-premise endpoint? The question as written is a bit vague - can you add more detail to clarify what you're asking for?

Comment: I want to call the webservices which are running on in-house server. These servers can't be accessed outside the organization . How can i access these servers for SFDC request. Is there something needs to be done from server side. I want to know what the best practices to authenticate SFDC request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguably, the most secure mechanism to make a callout from Salesforce to an on-premise web server is to use two-way SSL.

In this scenario, no usernames or passwords are exchanged. Instead, both the client (Salesforce) and the server (Your Host) present certificates to prove their identity to each other.

[Making Authenticated Web Service Callouts Using Two-Way SSL](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Making_Authenticated_Web_Service_Callouts_Using_Two-Way_SSL)

The web server(s) receiving these requests inside the organization firewall will need to be accessible from Salesforce. The requests will come from published IP addresses, to defined ports, which can be whitelisted at the edge of your network allowing you to secure the endpoint to allow only requests from Salesforce.

[Important Security Considerations](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_security.htm) (for Outbound Messaging, but same security principles apply)

Comment: We have two mechanisms that we use: two-way SSL and some OAuth-style tokens, depending on the service we're using. The calls go through an API endpoint that uses whitelisting and token permissions to determine which services the token can access. It certainly can be safe, it just takes careful design and implementation.